# How to pick open sets when trying to show that a function is continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I wish to show that $f(x) = \dfrac{1}{x}$ is continuous on ($\mathbb{R}_+$, | |) using the definition $f$ is continuous if preimage of open is open

I am not sure how to go about selecting the open sets to show this effect.

In general, suppose I am given $f: M \to N$ where $(M, d)$ and $(N, d')$ are metric spaces, how do I go about picking the open sets on $M, N$ respectively to demonstrate that $f$ is continuous?

It is enough to pick any arbitrary open sets? Or just the open balls? Is there a pattern or logic in the method used to demonstrate $f$ is continuous using open sets?

Comment: The definition says that you have to pick an arbitrary open set, but one can prove (just using some fairly simple set theory) that it is enough to use just open balls. (More generally it is enough to use just a base of the topology of the codomain.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From first principles, a function $f$ is continuous if and only if the preimage of **every** open set is open. So you need to show that every open set in the codomain has open preimage.

Now it's a bit more complicated based on what exactly you've been learning. If $\mathcal{B}$ is a basis for the topology of the codomain, then it suffices to prove that the preimage of each $B \in \mathcal{B}$ is open. The standard topology on the real line has basis formed by open balls, so it suffices to show that the preimage of an open ball is open.

One can phrase or prove analogous statements with less "topological phrasing" too, but the idea is the same.